# php 7.3 is crashing itself

Tags: php, nginx

stack :

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch)
Release:    9.5
Codename:   stretch

PHP 7.3.14-5+0~20200202.52+debian9~1.gbpa71879 (cli) (built: Feb  2 2020 07:56:57) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.14, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.3.14-5+0~20200202.52+debian9~1.gbpa71879, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by 
Zend Technologies
```

problem :

This server is working over a year now but from yesterday i have some issues with php (i hope)
I think that php is crashing and not reloading after something (i didn`t found problem)
it is causing

nginx log:

```
 2020/04/07 12:51:11 [crit] 770#770: *17055 connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock 
failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, 
server: ***, request: "GET /api/me HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "***"
2020/04/07 12:51:11 [crit] 770#770: *17057 connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock failed 
(2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: *
, request: "GET /api/seo/get? path=*** HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.3- 
fpm.sock:", host: "***"
```

question:
Do You guys know what can be fatal for php to kill his pid ?
Do Youd know any monitor that can brind that process back when crashed ?

alternate answer:
I can monitor it myself and make php7.3-fpm restart but it is time consuming ...

cheers

Edit:
as commment suggested i checked /var/log/php7.3-fpm log result below

```
[07-Apr-2020 11:05:19] NOTICE: [pool www] child 5504 started
[07-Apr-2020 11:14:42] WARNING: [pool www] server reached 
pm.max_children setting (6), consider raising it
[07-Apr-2020 11:32:18] WARNING: [pool www] server reached 
pm.max_children setting (6), consider raising it
[07-Apr-2020 11:54:21] WARNING: [pool www] server reached 
pm.max_children setting (6), consider raising it
[07-Apr-2020 12:02:26] WARNING: [pool www] server reached 
pm.max_children setting (6), consider raising it
[07-Apr-2020 12:30:16] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[07-Apr-2020 12:30:16] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
```

what is safe limit for php child nodes ?

Solution
changed pool.d/www.conf pm values to

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
pm.process_idle_timeout = 5s;
```

Comment: check /var/log for messages from php-fpm.

Comment: Looks like it is terminating gracefully. Does the kernel decide to terminate the PHP FPM server because some other process runs out of memory (OOM killer)?

Comment: free -m gives         
                     total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7797        5026        1211         105        1560        2383
Swap:             0           0           0
so there is plenty of space